# srcset only loads largest image

Tags: html, css, image

I have this image tag with a few different srcs and it's only loading the one. I feel like I followed the directions, but it's only loading the 600px width image (w_600 image).

```
<img 
  srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/tjblackman08/image/upload/w_600%2Cf_auto%2Cq_auto/Brads-House/4.jpg 600w,
    https://res.cloudinary.com/tjblackman08/image/upload/w_520%2Cf_auto%2Cq_auto/Brads-House/4.jpg 520w,
    https://res.cloudinary.com/tjblackman08/image/upload/w_440%2Cf_auto%2Cq_auto/Brads-House/4.jpg 440w,
    https://res.cloudinary.com/tjblackman08/image/upload/w_360%2Cf_auto%2Cq_auto/Brads-House/4.jpg 360w,
    https://res.cloudinary.com/tjblackman08/image/upload/w_280%2Cf_auto%2Cq_auto/Brads-House/4.jpg 280w" 
  sizes="(min-width: 1500px) 600px,
    (max-width: 1200px) 520px,
    (max-width: 992px) 440px,
    (max-width: 768px) 360px,
    (max-width: 480px) 280px" 
  src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tjblackman08/image/upload/w_600%2Cf_auto%2Cq_auto/Brads-House/4.jpg 600w" 
  alt="picture" 
  class="picture"
/>
```

Here's a [Live Demo](https://x-qbbdpkv6r.now.sh/)

I'm trying to get it to load the largest image one desktops, and the smallest image on mobile devices, but it'a always loading the large image. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of `srcset`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this and see,

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/tjblackman08/image/upload/w_600%2Cf_auto%2Cq_auto/Brads-House/4.jpg" media="(min-width: 1500px)">
    <source srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/tjblackman08/image/upload/w_520%2Cf_auto%2Cq_auto/Brads-House/4.jpg" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
    <source srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/tjblackman08/image/upload/w_440%2Cf_auto%2Cq_auto/Brads-House/4.jpg" media="(min-width: 992px)">
    <source srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/tjblackman08/image/upload/w_360%2Cf_auto%2Cq_auto/Brads-House/4.jpg" media=" (min-width: 768px)">
    <source srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/tjblackman08/image/upload/w_280%2Cf_auto%2Cq_auto/Brads-House/4.jpg" media="(min-width: 480px)">
    <img srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/tjblackman08/image/upload/w_280%2Cf_auto%2Cq_auto/Brads-House/4.jpg" alt="Placehold" class="image">
</picture>
```

Hope this helps.